# DNN Editing Icon Suddenly Disappear

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've got DNN Community Edition 06.02.01

It happens that, while site management, suddenly, all modules' editing icons suddenly disappear.

I really have no idea what I'm doing to make it happens...

Someone knows what's make those icons disappear?

No IIS reset works.

Only restoring the previous database backup works.

It seems that I make something that change the DB so that that icons disappears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in **Top DNN Panel** => **Right Side** => **DropDownList control** => Select **Edit Mode** instead of View Mode.

Make sure you are login with your **Host** OR **Admin** login credential.

Comment: It was so simple! And because I never use such mode I didn't look at that. Thanks.